# Xcode 14.2 not displaying errors despite troubleshooting steps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm facing a frustrating issue with Xcode 14.2, and I was hoping someone here could help me out. The problem is that Xcode is not showing any errors or warnings, even though I know there are issues in my code. I've tried a few troubleshooting steps, but none of them have resolved the problem so far.

Has anyone else encountered this problem with Xcode 14.2 or any other version? If so, how did you manage to resolve it? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights from the community.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Here's what I've done:
Deleted Derived Data: I went to Xcode preferences and deleted the derived data for my project. This usually helps in clearing any cached data that might be causing issues. Unfortunately, it didn't work in this case.
Unchecked "Show Live Errors" option: I also made sure that the "Show Live Errors" option in Xcode preferences was unchecked. This option can sometimes interfere with error display, but it didn't solve the problem for me.
Despite these attempts, I'm still stuck with the same issue. I'm unable to see any error indicators in my code, and it's making the debugging process extremely difficult. I'm sure there are errors in my code because I've tested it on other versions of Xcode, and they show the errors correctly.

Comment: Do they show up under Reports (Cmd-9) after you build the app?

Comment: yes they do show in the reports and also when i disable show live error and enable build after errors, errors do show up but they don't go away when I solved the error.

Comment: The only solution I found searching on SO is to check they every group in the navigation (left part) that is linked to a folder has the same name as the folder (check in right tab)

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem after updating from Xcode 14.3 to Xcode 14.3.1.

I saw the comment in reply to your question and checked for folders with mis-matched names, but this wasn't the problem. I already have "Show live issues" checked in the Xcode settings too.

I found that cleaning up Xcode project data did the trick:

- Close Xcode.
- Go to: About This Mac > More Info... > Storage Settings... > Developer
- Select **Xcode Caches** and delete.
- Wait until the entry disappears, then restart Xcode.
- If the problem is still not fixed, then it might help to repeat the process and delete **Project Build Data and indexes** too.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't worked!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue on XCode 15.2. Unfortunately, it doesn't work on my end.