# SwiftUI Previews not working after installing iOS 17 Simulator

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios17

I installed iOS 17 simulator and now the preview canvas doesn't work. I just keeps showing the spinner. It's the same for new projects and existing projects. Has anyone seen this behavior? I'm running Xcode 15.0 and MacOS 13.5.2. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: You could try cleaning the build folder (Product > Clean Build Folder...) and also [deleting the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421349/20386264).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem still remains.

Comment: I'm having the same issue for running the react-native app. It seems to be a problem with iOS emulator its self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I installed iOS Simulator version 17.0.1 and the Preview Canvas is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the simulator preview? It worked for me.

Comment: If you mean changing to a different simulator device, for example iPhone 15 vs. iPhone 15 Pro, I tried that but it didn't help.