# Why is my Xcode canvas not showing any device?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-previews

I am using Xcode version 14.3.1 and my canvas has randomly stopped working as usual. I never experienced an issue until now. Basically my canvas is displaying on the right hand side of the screen but it is empty. It isn't showing my view (it's just straight up not showing any device to present a view on).

I tried restarting my MacBook, restarting Xcode, messing with all of the canvas settings within Xcode but nothing has worked so far. Not sure if anyone else has experienced this issue. Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of Xcode]

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project, to check whether it's something wrong in your current project's setup?

Comment: yeah i created a new project and opened a few other's and the issue still recurs

Comment: @Nate tried to update or download Xcode. Or try clear Derived Data. If you want to use same version try to uninstall and install same version.

Comment: Is there any error Xcode generates for you while rendering previews?

Comment: A cleanup might help as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421349/20386264)