# Problem after updating Xcode from v9.4.1 to v10.0

Tags: xcode

I'm facing an issue after updating Xcode from v9.4.1 to v10.0. When I attempt to build my tvOS project, I encounter the following error:

> unexpected duplicate task: CopyPlistFile /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication/Build/Products/Debug-appletvos/MyApplication.app/Settings.plist /Users/username/project_folder/Settings.plist (in target 'MyApplicationTarget') *https://promo-codes.cz/*

I haven't tried anything yet. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Try a cleanup. See the answer to [Xcode 14.2 not displaying errors despite troubleshooting steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421349/20386264)

Comment: Also, check build phases of your target. However, out of curiosity, I have an unrelated question: why would you use Xcode 9 or 10 in 2024, since the most recent version is Xcode 15?