# Xcode hangs when opening a project - how to reset ALL settings?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running Xcode 15.2 on macOS Sonoma 14.3.1 (23D60) on a M1 Pro Macbook.

When I try creating a new project, or try opening an existing one, Xcode hangs for around 10-15 minutes before opening the project and continuing to work normally. If I try to open another project, it will still hang for 10-15 minutes.

<s>I tried creating a different user on macOS, and that user does not have the same problem with Xcode.</s> -> After a few days it started happening with the new user as well

So it seems like the issue is with the settings tied to my specific user.

But whatever I try to do, I cannot seem to reset the settings completely.
I can tell because on Xcode home screen I can see my recent projects, and it should be blank - it's obviously pulling that information from somewhere - the question is from where?

I have iCloud on my machine, but iCloud Drive is completely turned off.
The projects I am trying to open are not in Documents or Desktop.

This is what I tried to do:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
rm -rf /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/MobileDevice
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Xcode
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.dt.Xcode/RecentlyOpenedProjects.plist
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Saved Application State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState
```

And i also deleted the Derived Data folder.

After running those commands and restarting my machine - Xcode still hangs when opening a project, and I can still see my recent projects in Xcode.

How do I reset Xcode to factory settings?

EDIT: Even though it worked with a new user for a few days, now it randomly stopped working with my new user - Xcode takes 10-15 minutes to open projects. It seems completely random. I closed a project, tried opening it again and all of a sudden it stops loading projects in a timely manner

I am still actively looking for a solution for this issue

Comment: Did you try deleting the `DerivedData` folder?

Comment: "I tried creating a different user on macOS, and that user does not have the same problem with Xcode" Great. So migrate into that user and throw away the hosed user. Problem solved. You've answered your own question.

Comment: @shim yes i also deleted the derived data folder but it didn't help.

Comment: @matt it no longer works with the new user, it did for a few days, but now I'm back to 10-15 minute loading. It seems completely random. I closed a project , tried reopening it and all of a sudden it stops loading projects in a timely manner

Comment: There is key to keep pressed when launching an app that launch it without its "settings/cache", and helped me in the past where Xcode was stuck on launching. I can't find it back, maybe it was keeping "Option" pressed... Might be something to dig. But also, with your Xcode stuck, you might check which files causes the issues (or multiple ones)... I remembered on an old Xcode version that it crashes/failed on opening storyboard because I renamed by "home" (and the paths didn't liked that at it was uppercase/lowercase changed)

Comment: @Larme That's Shift.

Comment: Instead of deleting the files by hand you could also try a cleanup from the system storage settings. See the answer to [Xcode 14.2 not displaying errors despite troubleshooting steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421349/20386264) for details.

Comment: @BenzyNeez thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it did not make any difference

Comment: You said that the projects that you are opening are neither in documents nor the desktop. Where are they actually? Maybe that is a location where Xcode runs into issue creating derived data?

Comment: @DatBlaueHus my projects are in `~/Developer` directory

Comment: Try looking in `~/Library/Autosave Information`. Probably will not help but worth a shot.

Comment: @CPlus that folder is empty for me