iOS framework build error - Build input file cannot be found
I'm getting this error while building my iOS framework:

Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/######/Movahed/Plankton/IOS/plankton/DerivedData/plankton/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/plankton.framework/plankton'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?


It's happening in the Extract app intents metadata phase.
I tried every solution suggested in similar questions, but none of them worked. I also built the project with several versions of xcode 14 and 15(including 15.3) and the macOS versions was 14.4 and 13.6.5
Notice that the missing file that the error message is referencing, is not one of the source files of the project and should probably be generated during the build.
I also noticed that when I remove all of the files(.swift and .m) from Build Phases > Compile Sources, the framework builds successfully

Have you tried cleaning up the derived data? Try the below tool to smartly cleanup the derived data and restart Xcode then see, hopefully it will resolve your issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78149876/xcode-hangs-when-opening-a-project-how-to-reset-all-settings
