# Xcode broken: Previews working in a SwiftUI project

Tags: xcode

my xcode is stuck in preview mode even in the default app. "preview iphone simulator for previews" take for ever to load. I try to deinstall and reinstall but nothing is working. I did the last sonoma update, same thing. any idea?

Comment: Try a cleanup. See the answer to [Xcode 14.2 not displaying errors despite troubleshooting steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421349/20386264)

Comment: it didn't work. still stuck. any other idea?