# The code of the AppDelegate class in Xcode suddenly became colorless

Tags: xcode, appdelegate

all of a sudden, the code within the AppDelegate class in Xcode lost its color. There are no color issues in other classes, only in the AppDelegate class.I have no idea how to solve it. I restarted the project. I tried the "Clean and Build" option, but the problem persists. I would greatly appreciate your help.

While using the application normally, I encountered one of the typical errors (empty array, API error, etc.). However, when I returned, the AppDelegate was corrupted.

[image: appDelegate class ss]

Comment: You could try a clean-up as described in the answer to [Xcode 14.2 not displaying errors despite troubleshooting steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421349/20386264)

Comment: What does Xcode show in "Editor" -> "Syntax Coloring"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to check the settings in Xcode. Go to "Editor" -> "Syntax Coloring" and see what options are selected there.